# How to get/fetch the environment variables set in Jenkins pipeline into our maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pom.xml

I have couple of Environment variables set using Jenkins pipeline.

[image]

I want to fetch the values of these environment variables in my maven pom.xml file, where I want to pass them as buildArgs to docker-maven-plugin, which will be again called in a dockerfile.

[image]

How to call those environment variables in my pom.xml?

I tried `${env.JENKINS_USER_NAME}` as well as `%JENKINS_USER_NAME%` but nothing seem to work.

**Use case:** I will be running my Jenkins pipeline job to build my project, which will eventually create an docker image in Stage-1 and then run the docker container in Stage-2 (which will run the tests as well internally).

**Problem:** My Jenkins job can be triggered based on user selection of specific testng.xml file as show below:

[image]

When triggered once, it is working fine but if we triggered for second time without cleaning the workspace, then it is throwing error like

[image]

I am assuming that it might be a problem with permission, as I am mounting volume to map container test-output directory with Jenkins host-VM directory

[image]

How can I get the environment variables in my POM?

Comment: Several questions. What is your main problem? #1 Passing env variables from jenkins pipeline to your app (pom.xml)  #2 The second execution which throws an error? #3 If your java app is standard I advice to use a clean Dockerfile instead maven plugins. I provide you a Dockerfile if it helps you

Comment: #1 is my question. Remaining details to describe the use case. In relates to the #3, we need to use the docker-maven plugin as there are couple other requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the values as [maven properties (with defaults)](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties), then you can override them on the maven command line with properties from the Jenkins environment variable populated from the drop-down.

**pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
        <gid>default-gid</gid> 
        <uid>default-uid/<uid> 
        <uname>default-uname</uname> 
</properties>

<configuration>
    <buildArgs>
        <GID>${gid}</GID> 
        <UID>${uid}/<UID> 
        <UNAME>${uname}</UNAME> 
    </buildArgs> 
</configuration>
```

**SH EXEC CMD:**

`mvn -Dgid=my-gid -Duid=my-uid -Duname=my-uname clean system-test:latest ${TestSuiteFiles}`